# What is %P in Tcl?

Tags: validation, tcl, tkinter-entry

I saw this code en Tcl:

```
entry .amount -validate key -validatecommand {
    expr {[string is int %P] || [string length %P]==0}
}
```

I know that it's an entry validation but, what does "%P" in that code? I was looking in the Tcl's doc but I didn't find nothing.

I think this is another way to do it but it has the same symbols:

```
proc check_the_input_only_allows_digits_only {P} {
    expr {[string is int P] || [string length P] == 0}
}
entry .amount \
    -validate key \
    -validatecommand {check_the_input_only_allows_digits_only %P}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tcl-tk page for `entry` says

> **%P**
>
> The value of the entry if the edit is allowed. If you are configuring the entry widget to have a new textvariable, this will be the value of that textvariable.

https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/entry.html#M25

Comment: So, The %P it's the new text that the entry will display? Or it's the new character that will be added to the entry text? I didn't understand the "textvariable" very well, can u explain me that concept?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.   Please see if the explanation is in that tcl-tk page.

Comment: Well it appears but isn't well explained, Thanks for all, It helps me a lot.

Comment: https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/entry.html#M25 is a more up-to-date link. Text's pretty much identical though; feature's not changed in that time. Textvariables are documented at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/options.html#M-textvariable (as it is a feature used by many widgets).

Comment: I saw that it's just a variable that refference the text inside an entry, however, I also saw other like %V for example, and I wanna know if that only pass the event type(key, focusIn, ...) to the callback, just in case it is required for the validation, and there is also a %S, I don't know how it's related that to the validation.

Answer (score 0):

> I think this is another way to do it but it has the same symbols:

You're close. You just have to use `$` in a few places because you're just running a procedure and that's as normal for using parameters to procedures.

```
proc check_the_input_only_allows_digits_only {P} {
    expr {[string is int $P] || [string length $P] == 0}
}
entry .amount \
    -validate key \
    -validatecommand {check_the_input_only_allows_digits_only %P}
```

It's *recommended* that you write things like that using a procedure for anything other than the most trivial of validations (or other callbacks); putting the complexity directly in the callback gets confusing quickly.

I recommend keeping validation loose during the input phase, and only making stuff strictly validated on form submission (or pressing the `OK`/`Apply` button, or whatever it is that makes sense in the GUI) precisely because it's *really* convenient to have invalid states there for a while in many forms while the input is being inputted. Per-key validation therefore probably should be used to only indicate whether it's believed that form submission will work, not to outright stop even transients from existing.

---

The `string is int` command returns true for zero-length input precisely because it was originally put in to work with that validation mechanism. It grinds my gears that *actual* validation of an integer needs `string is int -strict`. Can't change it now though; it's just a wrong default…

```
entry .amount -validate key -validatecommand {string is int %P}
```